# Remove Skype 4.3 from Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, uninstallation, skype

**Description:**

> To remove Skype 4.3 from Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (32-bit)

Answer (score 6):

To remove Skype for linux, open terminal and run command

`sudo apt-get purge skypeforlinux`

Answer (score 2):

To remove Skype 4.3 from Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (32-bit)

Open Terminal and type (Copy+paste is better option) and press Enter button

> sudo apt-get purge skype

Also try this

> sudo apt-get autoremove skype